# verbs after the verb "stop"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I read in my grammar book that if there is a verb after "stop", it will be in present continuous form: I mean in "ing" form. But I found the following sentence in the book:

> You might stop to look in this when you're walking along a street.

Is above sentence correct? why?

Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-ing" forms are used with a verb whose action is to be stopped. In your example sentence, the action that is stopped is not mentioned explicitly:
"stop walking", or "stop moving" or "stop driving", and you are to do that in order to "look". So the structure of this sentence is different.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you were told is too simplistic. The example sentence is perfectly valid. Note that it doesn't explicitly say what it is that you will stop doing. Presumably the writer means that you will stop walking, and "walking" is a present continuous. But that word isn't actually in the sentence, it's just implied. Well, the word "walking" is in the sentence, but not as the target of the word "stop". And one can easily imagine a sentence where it is present at all: just drop everything in that sentence from the word "then" on.